# "Invalid URL: words" - apollo-server

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I would like to create small project using GraphqQL, ApolloServer, but I encountered a problem, that I can't solve. 
I wrote it based on several documentation.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const { RESTDataSource } = require('apollo-datasource-rest');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Word {
    id: ID!
    word: String!
    translation: String!
  }
  type Query {
    words: [Word]
    word(id: ID): Word
  }
`;

class WordsAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseURL = 'localhost:5001/'
  }

  async getWord(id) {
    return this.get(`word/${id}`)
  }

  async getAllWords() {
    return this.get('words')
  }

  async getSpecifiedWords(SpecWord) {
    return this.get(`words/${SpecWord}`)
  }
}

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    words: (_, __, { dataSources }) =>
      dataSources.wordsAPI.getAllWords(),
    word: async (_source, { id }, { dataSources }) => {
      return dataSources.wordsAPI.getWord(id);
    }
  }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => {
    return {
      wordsAPI: new WordsAPI()
    };
  },
  context: () => {
    return {
    };
  },
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

After

```
query {
 words {
   translation
 }
}
```

In playground I am getting Invalid URL: words. 
 
At localhost:5001/words is database and in Postman it works.
What did I bad?

Comment: Your datasource is named `wordsAPI`, not `WordsAPI`

Comment: Thanks! Yes you are right. I just saw it and fix it, but I have another issue. More info in updated post.

Comment: Your `baseUrl` should probably start with "http://".

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it was missing. At first I tried to add "https://" (it doesn't work) but I didn't think about "http://".